# MVC4 jquery scripting

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am used to MVC2... Where you simply add your links to scripts and your sources to the view and just call the jquery function and viola... You have working Jquery code.  But I am unable to get my jqGrid tableToGrid function working.  I am guessing cause I am not loading the jquery libraries in right at all or I am not running the scripts in the right place.  Could you take a look at my code and see what could possible be wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>ShowAllEncounters</title>
 <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
```

This would be the head...
I previously had my scripts linked in there as well... But that didn't work... So I put outside of the  tag... like so...

```
</html>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
...});
```

Am I missing something?  How does one go about scripting jquery in an MVC4 site?

I can't even get a freaking alert to show up!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
@model IEnumerable<FocusedReadMissionsRedux.Models.TemplateModel>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js")" type="text/javascript"/>
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css")" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("what is going on");
       });
   </script>
   <title>ShowAllEncounters</title>
</head>
```

UPDATE:  It would seem as though I am having an issue with when the jquery libraries are being loaded.  Which would definitely be a problem.  I need a solid pattern for adding these scripts to a project?

Comment: Are you loading the Jquery library before the jqgrid, in your example Jquery is not loaded at all?

Comment: View the html source, then try going to the `.js` file in your browser and see if it loads. Also, what fbfcn said.

Comment: I am loading the jquery library before jqGrid.
Is it to much to ask for a simple example of loading ANY jquery library?

Comment: I believe in MVC4 doing @Url.Content and ~/ are the same thing, so you may want to try one or the other. http://www.beletsky.net/2012/04/new-in-aspnet-mvc4-razor-changes.html

Comment: didn't work.  Infact, when I got rid of the Url.content functions my css disapeared.  I can't believe I can't find a simple example of how to load jquery in mvc4?  This is freaking ridiculous

Comment: Please be sure to strip the profanity from your code before posting to SO. See [Are expletives allowed on SE sites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-on-se-sites).

Comment: Where's the `jquery.js` script inclusion in your last code sample? I can see that you have included `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` but without including jQuery that is very unlikely to work. jqGrid has a dependency on jQuery so make sure you have referenced it correctly.

Comment: order should be `jquery.version.js` -> `your.plugin.js` -- plugins are not standalone

Comment: where do you get the jquery.js script file?  Shouldn't that be included in the jquery nugget thing?  There is no jquery.js in my Scripts list.  Where in the heck do you go to get that?

Comment: It's in the Scripts folder when you create a new ASP.NET MVC application. If you removed it by mistake you could always install the jquery NuGet or download it from the official jquery site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the "new" MVC4 templates, jquery scripts are added at the "bottom" of the _layout.cshtml via Bundles.

Move the @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") within your  block of the _layout.cshtml.

I'm not sure why the template puts this script include at the end of the html file...

Comment: As it seems, this is one of the ways to ensure that the page is fully loaded. It's a poor man's vision, to me, as they are using JQuery and it has a list of facilities fur such endeavour...

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to Patrice answer (just to clarify to future visitors).

The Bundle can be customized at /App_Start/BundleConfig.cs.

As NoProblemBabe said, the Bundles with Javascript content are put in the end of html file to assure the loading Javascript files at first access won't stuck the rest of HTML file loading, it will present the page faster to client.

As jQuery start functions are put in $(document).ready (in a well coding practice), there's no big deal with it.
Plus, browser caching of JS files is a point to remember. (that will probably be enabled in a almost totally of browsers).